# error: Non-nullable instance field 'searchSnapshot' must be initialized

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class DiscoverScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DiscoverScreenState createState() => _DiscoverScreenState();
}

class _DiscoverScreenState extends State<DiscoverScreen> {

  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();
  TextEditingController searchUserController = new TextEditingController();
  QuerySnapshot searchSnapshot;

  bool isLoading = false;
  bool haveUserSearched = false;
```

I'm getting a use as late error, but when I use it as late, I get this error -> LateInitializationError: Field 'searchSnapshot' has not been initialized.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have value of variable while initializing it you must have to make it a nullable by using **?** operator.

```
QuerySnapshot? searchSnapshot;
```

if you still want to make it non-nullable just assign a value while declaring or use **late** keyword in this case you have to assign a value to this variable in initState.

```
late QuerySnapshot searchSnapshot;
```